# Never show two divs at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on a project where ng-cloak is unavailable due to the way the css files are loaded, so I'm looking for a less worse solution and have tried a few different things.

I never want to show these two icons at the same time. The problem is, the bottom one (angle right) shows up briefly since the promise for the data source is still resolving. How can I make sure these two icons will never show up at once?

```
  <i class=" fa invalid-data-icon fa-angle-down" ng-hide="vm.hideInvalid"
                           ng-show="vm.data.datasources.length">
 </i>

<i class="fa invalid-data-icon fa-angle-right" ng-show="vm.hideInvalid"
                           ng-hide="vm.data.datasources.length">
</i>
```

EDIT:

went with this from the accepted answer:

```
<i class=" fa invalid-data-icon fa-angle-down" ng-class="{'rotate-icon':vm.data.datasources[1].length==0 || vm.hideInvalid}"></i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative approach: Only use one icon in your code, and rotate it with a css class:

`<i class=" fa invalid-data-icon fa-angle-down" ng-class={'rotate-icon':!!vm.data.datasources.length}></i>`

(my Angular skills are a bit rusty, but you get the jist...)

Then in your CSS, something like this:

```
.rotate-icon {
  transform: rotate(-90deg)
}
```

Comment: this was an awesome answer, decluttered my code big time. clearly frameworks/languages aren't a barrier for you :)

Comment: Haha, I wouldn't go that far.

Answer (score 2):

First using but ng-show and ng-hide in the same tag is a pretty bad idea.

You should do something like :

```
<i class=" fa invalid-data-icon fa-angle-down" 
    ng-show="vm.hideInvalid==false && vm.data.datasources.length==0">
</i>

<i class="fa invalid-data-icon fa-angle-right" 
     ng-show="vm.hideInvalid==true && vm.data.datasources.length==0">
</i>
```

Considering that as long your promise is not resvoled you would have initialize hideInvalid and datasources to undefined.